# Вывод данных из SQLite в String []

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть некая таблица в SQLite из неё мы выводим все значения в строковую переменную.
Вот, что я сообразил:

```
    Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE, null); 
    int result = cursor.getColumnCount();
    int result1 = cursor.getCount();
    int result2 = result*result1; // количество значений в таблице (получилось то, что нужно)
    String [] def = new String[result2-2];
    def [0] = " 1 "; //первое значение мне нужно своё и дальше я добавляю данные начиная с 3.
    for (int d = 0; d < result1-1; d++) {
        Cursor cursor1 = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE + " WHERE ID = " + d, null);
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result2; j++){
        do {
            for (int k = 3; k < result-1; k++){
                j=+1;
                def [j] = cursor1.getString(k); 
                /* здесь ошибка E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: anem.tr, PID: 2580
                android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1 */
            }
        } while (cursor1.moveToNext());}
    } }
    return def;
}
```

Из ошибки я могу понять, что мой курсор становится не на то значение и просто не передвигается дальше, но где я здесь нахимичил не могу разобраться, поэтому прошу помощи.
В простом случае, когда работаю с одной строкой, все работает.

Comment: уберите во всех условиях знак равенства `d < ` **=** `result1-1`

Comment: Спасибо, знак убрал, ошибка осталась прежней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посидел сам, посчитал, в итоге получился такой ответ:

```
    int result2 = (cursor.getColumnCount()*cursor.getCount())-(3*(result1));  
    String [] def = new String[result2+1];
    int j = 0;
    do {
        Cursor cursor1 = null;
        do {
            for (int d = 0; d < result1; d++) {
                cursor1 = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE + " WHERE ID = " + d, null);
                if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int k = 3; k < result; k++){
                        j++;
                        def [j] = cursor1.getString(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
    }  while (j == result2+1);
    return def;
```

Отобразил только изменившийся код, получился практически весь.
**Первая ошибка** была в определении количества значений в таблице, как выяснилось при обычном перемножении терялись значения, поэтому пришлось переосмыслить и переписать формулу, где у меня убирается три первых столбца из таблицы и остальные записываются в массив.
**Вторая ошибка** в расстановке циклов **for**, сначала я выбирал строку, потом шёл по всему массиву в попытках записать первую строку в весь массив, который был явно больше данной строки. В итоге поменял два цикла местами и получилось, как мне нужно, сначала массив начинается с 0 значения, которое у меня уже присвоено. Потом мы берём строку, третье значение строки записываем в массив с индексом 1 и параллельно увеличиваем значение j, строка заканчивается, берем новую и так пока значение j не будет равно всему массиву (массив больше на 1 значение, т.к. вначале мы записываем в массив с индексом 0 "1").
Не знаю, как повысить карму всем, кто отвечал, т.к. в их ответах тоже были указания на мои ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        //Здесь берёшь данные из курсора и делаешь с ними всё что нужно 


            cursor.moveToNext();

        }

        cursor.close();
```

И пересмотри логику в циклах, я уверен что там можно написать всё гораздо изящнее.

Comment: Да я старой закалки, хотел бы я сказать, но чувствуется недостаток знаний...

Comment: Так сказать, при перестановке слагаемых, сумма не меняется. Ошибка прежняя.

Answer (score 0):

j=+1; Это присваивание значения = 1, после первой итерации j-2 будет = -1, отсюда и ошибка. Возможно вместо j=+1 имелось в виду j+=1.

Comment: Походу так и есть, но теперь

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: PID: 3040
                  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Я же говорил что нужно алгоритм пересмотреть, в массиве же нумерация начинается с 0, for (int j = 3; j <= result2-1; j++) - здесь j инициализируется 3, def [j-2]  - здесь идёт обращение по индексу [1], если в массиве только 1 элемент, то его индекс 0 .

Comment: Сначала в массив с индексом 0 я помещаю своё значение, затем в массив с индексом 1 помещаю значение из третьего столбца таблицы, попутно увеличивая значение j, чтобы каждое новое значение записывалось с новым индексом и так, пока строка не закончится. До меня только дошло, что смысла j начинать с 3 нет, надо бы начать с 1, тогда путаницы меньше получается, но ошибка конечно не в этом.

Comment: Была небольшая ошибка в названии массива.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог с ошибкой, пометь его как правильный.

Comment: К сожалению не помог, я бы уже отметил. Я подправил первое сообщение со всеми правками и результат все тот же.

Comment: Опиши задачу, я подумаю на досуге как цикл записать.

Comment: Существует таблица в SQLite из неё необходимо считать данные построчно и записать их в один массив, который заранее задан, или каждую строку в новый массив, который автоматически генерируется по известному принципу. Количество строк и столбцов вычисляется автоматически исходя из заданной таблицы. Вот основная задача на текущий момент.

Comment: В конечном итоге, я хочу выводить данный массив на экран и получать обычную таблицу.

Comment: В динамический массив типа ArrayList можно спокойно добавлять объекты, без танцев с бубнами и выяснения размера, если после этого необходим просто массив, то из ArrayLista он тоже извлекается, так же ArrayList можно отсортировать при помощи собственно создананого Comparator.

Comment: Дело ещё в том, что я использую библиотеку для вывода данных из SQLite в виде таблицы, где необходимо собирать всё, именно в такой массив.

Comment: Вообще для любой более-менее замороченной логики классы из java.util.collections подходят больше чем массив, почитай про коллекции, там однозначно есть все структуры данных, которые нужны, и делать с ними тоже можно всё что нужно.